# ClassifierMeasurements Indeterminate Examples

Tags: machine-learning

I like to use `ClassifierMeasurements`. It's nice and doesn't make me think too hard.  One of the features I like a lot is the `Examples` which lets me easily inspect misclassified examples.  Another feature I really like is the `IndeterminateThreshold` option.  However, when using the `IndeterminateThreshold` option I can't seem to figure out how to extract "IndeterminateExamples".  For example I can get three 9's accuracy with `IndeterminateThreshold -> 0.89774` and there are 43 samples in each class that are `Indeterminate`.  If I wanted to know which sample was misclassified as 0 I could enter something like `cm["Examples" -> {1, 0}]`.

**So then, is there a way to ask a ClassifierMeasurement object for "IndeterminateExamples"**?

[image]

P.S. I realize I can calculate this directly but the question is if it is possible to ask `ClassifierMeasurements` for this info.  It is clear from the confusion matrix plot that `ClassifierMeasurements` figured out which samples where Indeterminate so how do I access that information?

Answer (score 1):

While `Indeterminate` is not a class per se, looks like it can be used with the `Examples` option just like a class label.  I was able to get the indeterminate samples using

`cm["Examples" -> {1, Indeterminate}]`